# insert array to database with query builder and unset array when find same value

Tags: laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-query-builder

im want to insert array to db with query builder on laravel controller, and i get error,
I also haven't found a way to prohibit the same data from entering the database

my foreach :

```
  $like = '123';
  foreach($list as $data) {
    $filter = array_filter($data, function ($item) use ($like) {
        if (stripos($item['number'], $like) !== false) {
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
  }
```

im trying to dd($filter); and get array like this :

```
^ array:3 [▼
1 => array:2 [▼
    "number" => "123"
    "desc" => "tester1"
]
2 => array:2 [▼
    "number" => "578"
    "desc" => "tester2"
]
4 => array:2 [▼
    "number" => "123"
    "desc" => "tester3"
]
```

my query builder

```
   DB::table('myData')->insert(
     ['number' => $filter['number'], 'desc' =>$filter['desc']
   );
```

error log in line $filter['number']:

> Undefined index: number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use foreach loop:

```
foreach($filter as $item)
{
    DB::table('myData')->insert(
         ['number' => $item['number'], 'desc' =>$item['desc']
    );
}
```

Comment: its work, but only show one data array, how to still fetch all array data ?

Answer (score 1):

In a more simpler way, As your output is

```
array:3 [▼
1 => array:2 [▼
    "number" => "123"
    "desc" => "tester1"
]
2 => array:2 [▼
    "number" => "578"
    "desc" => "tester2"
]
4 => array:2 [▼
    "number" => "123"
    "desc" => "tester3"
]
```

which has the same index as table columns, so you can just pass `$filter` into insert method.
eg.

```
DB::table('myData')->insert($filter);
```

This will handle multiple records insert. for more help
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/insert-multiple-records-in-one-query

Answer (score -1):

As I can see you have a multidimensional array, so you have to run two foreach loops to access the number index

```
$like = '123';
  foreach($list as $data) {
    $filter = array_filter($data, function ($item) use ($like) {
        foreach($item as $value) {
            if (stripos($value['number'], $like) !== false) {
           return true;
        }
        return false;
        }
        
    });
  }
```